# Regex: replace all numbers and "number-like" strings except for years in range

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
s = '2014 2026 202 20 1000 1949 194 195092 20111a a2011a a2011 keep this text n0t th1s th0ugh 1 0 2015 2025 2026'
```

I want to replace with `''` every part of this string which contains a number, **except for those parts of the string that are in the year range 1950 to 2025**. The resultant string would look like this (don't worry about the extraneous whitespace):

```
'2014          keep this text      2015 2025 '
```

So, effectively I want the brute-force removal of anything and everything remotely "numerical," except for something **standalone** (i.e. not part of another string, and of length 4 excluding whitespace) that resembles a year.

I know I can use this to remove *everything* containing digits:

```
re.sub('\w*[0-9]\w*', '', s)
```

But that doesn't return what I want:

```
'           keep this text        '
```

Here's my attempt at replacing anything that doesn't match the patterns listed below:

```
re.sub(r'^([A-Za-z]+|19[5-9]\d|20[0-1]\d|202[0-5])', '*', s)
```

Which returns:

```
'* 2026 202 20 1000 1949 194 195092 20111a a2011a a2011 keep this text n0t th1s th0ugh 1 0 2015 2025 2026'
```

I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374185/regular-expression-match-to-test-for-a-valid-year) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829875/python-number-range-to-regex-matching-string), but wasn't able to find what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you need to keep all these whitespaces in the result?

Comment: No, I'll eventually just strip those out. But that's an easy task. I'm more concerned about the number-like removal excluding years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
s = '2014 2026 202 20 1000 1949 194 195092 20111a a2011a a2011 keep this text n0t th1s th0ugh 1 0 2015 2025 2026'
result = ''.join(re.findall(r'\b(19[5-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9]|202[0-5]|[a-z]+|[^0-9a-z]+)\b', s, re.I))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
2014           keep this text      2015 2025
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex isn't good at working with numbers. I would ditch regex and use a generator expression:

```
predicate= lambda w: (w.isdigit() and 1950<=int(w)<=2025) or not any(char.isdigit() for char in w)
print(' '.join(w for w in s.split() if predicate(w)))
```

Comment: Maybe... `(w.isdigit() and 1950<=int(w)<=2025) or w.isalpha())` ?

Comment: @JonClements `isalpha()` isn't the same thing as not containing any digits. Any sort of punctuation or other special character would cause a word to be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this because it's readable and easy to fix of to improve:

```
' '.join(
    filter(
        lambda word: (word.isdigit() and \
                      int(word) >= 1950 and \
                      int(word) <= 2025) or \
                     re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', word),
        s.split()
    )
)
# '2014 keep this text 2015 2025'
```

Comment: Nice, but what about years in the range 1950-1999?